# How to do a bulk update in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with set of data. The table data will be as follows.

```
ID | Name | Age
----------------
1  |  A   | 24
2  |  B   | 25
3  |  C   | 30
4  |  D   | 46
5  |  E   | 35
6  |  F   | 26
7  |  G   | 30
```

Now, what I want is to update the age column for certain IDs, so that the end result will be as follows.

```
ID | Name | Age
----------------
1  |  A   | 24
2  |  B   | 22
3  |  C   | 35
4  |  D   | 50
5  |  E   | 27
6  |  F   | 26
7  |  G   | 30
```

I updated the rows where the ID = 2, 3, 4, 5

How can I achieve this result through a single T-SQL query? This is just a sample table. In real case, it's a table with over 1500 data, so that it consumes a lot of time to update the rows individually.

---

I found a solution, but I can't add it as an answer. So I decided to edit my own question and put the answer. Please refer the below url for more info:

www.stackoverflow.com/questions/16932526/…

```
           UPDATE e 
           SET age = t.age 
           FROM table e 
           JOIN ( VALUES 
           (1, 26), 
           (2, 30), 
           (3, 35) ) 
           t (id, age) ON t.id = e.id
```

Comment: Add the new data into a **staging** table, and then using a single `UPDATE` statement with a `JOIN`, you can update all revelant rows. No **loops** or **cursors** or other RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing needed !

Comment: What you mean with "certain"? What's the criteria?

Comment: @ArunPrasanth Thank you for sharing your opinion. I sure will look into it.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for sharing your method. I sure will look into it.

Comment: @king.code No such criteria. We were given the relevant age details with their respective IDs so that we have to update the necessary rows accordingly.

Comment: I had similar senario,If you have all the rows in source that consist changed and unchanged rows, I prefer to delete all existing records and insert fresh copy using SQLBulkCopy , this gives a great performance.

Comment: @ImranRizvi your method will have an effect on the primary key, because it's an auto increment value. Thanks a lot for sharing your opinion anyway.

Comment: I know, but it did not matter for me. does it matter for you? you have relationship on primary keys?

Comment: @ImranRizvi yes. It matters, because I have a huge database to deal with. And this is not the real table. The real case has a table with over 20 columns and over 2000 data and it's connected with few  other tables as well.

Answer (score 5):

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE mytable SET age=99 WHERE id=2
UPDATE mytable SET age=99 WHERE id=3
UPDATE mytable SET age=99 WHERE id=4
UPDATE mytable SET age=99 WHERE id=5
COMMIT TRAN
```

Look "stupid" but it is single query.

Comment: It doesn't look stupid. Even though it takes time to proceed from this method, still it provides an answer. Thank you very much for sharing the idea. I sure will look into it. If you have any other methods, please be kind enough to share them here as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Following script should do the trick:

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET Age = CASE WHEN Age = 25 THEN 22
             WHEN Age = 30 THEN 35
             WHEN Age = 46 THEN 50
             WHEN Age = 35 THEN 27
             END
WHERE ID IN (2,3,4,5)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can use the WHEN keyword, still for a bulk update, it'll consume a lot of time. Anyway, thank you very much for sharing your opinion. I sure will look into this method.

Answer (score 2):

Update in join would be my choice:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.AGE = T2.AGE
FROM T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT 2 AS ID, 22 AS AGE UNION
            SELECT 3, 35 UNION
            SELECT 4, 50 UNION
            SELECT 5, 27) AS T2
   ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

If they gave you the list of ID to update and the age, you can easily generate the inner select union in excel with a formula and place it there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your opinion. I sure will look into this method.

Answer (score 1):

you should rean on [update statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html). now there are many ways to achieve what you want, for example, you can see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69269/mysql-updating-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-one-query-for-dummies). a simple example will be:

```
UPDATE mytable SET
    Age= CASE WHEN id=2 THEN 22 WHEN id=3 THEN 35  WHEN id=4 THEN 50 WHEN id=5 THEN 27 END
WHERE id IN (2, 3, 4, 5);
```

for more reading on cases go [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)

Comment: It will work but far away from excellent solution.

Comment: True. This is working. But the issue is when you have to do a bulk update (eg: for more than 1500 data). Anyway, thanks a lot. I'll refer the links you have shared.

Comment: @i486 agreed, then again, this question is far from common way to do things

Comment: Although that is easy to achieve with REGEX, that is not the best way to do it

Comment: @SahanDeSilva usally when you have a bulk update then you have a logic of what the change mean (for example increment the age by 1) and then you don't need a specific case like here